# Display flex doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to set a section with `display: flex` using CSS, but it seems I can't do it. I tried so many different combos with CSS and the result is just changing the size of my section, but the element goes outside when the section reach the max-height that I set up.

Here is my HTML code where I want to display the element in flex mode:

```
<section id="BattlesH" class="flex-container">
    <h3><a name="hiphop">HipHop</a></h3>
    <div id="MyApp">
        <% if (req.user) { %>
            <input type="button" value="Show Hide DIV" v-on:click="ShowHide" />
        <%}%>
        <div v-show = "IsVisible">
            <label for="youtube">YouTube url</label>
            <input type="text" id="youtube" v-model="text" placeholder="Paste your YouTube video link"><br>
            <button  v-on:click="loadVideo">Add Video</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id="wrapPartecipant1" class="videoYoutube" v-for="item in videos">
        <section>
            <!-- IFRAME PER OGNI VIDEO CONTENUTO NEL DB -->
            <iframe class="partecipant"  v-bind:src="item.video.url"> </iframe>
            <!-- PRELEVO DAL DB IL CONTEGGIO DEI VOTI -->
            <p id="voti" > {{item.count}}  </p>
            <% if (req.user) { %>
                <!-- AGGIUNGO UN VOTO -->
                <input type="button" id="buttonVoti" v-on:click="addVoto(item._id)">
                <!--<iframe id="partecipant1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/............"></iframe>-->
            <%}%>
        </section>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```css
.flex-container{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
    #BattlesH{
    /*width:700px;*/
    height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    margin:5px;
    padding: 10px;
    /*float:right;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:2px solid black;
    background:#ccffcc;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
```

In some places there are comments; I used them to see if changing them can get some results, but nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You question should contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead of including server side code please include the generated markup. Also consider making a Stack Snippet so there is a verifiable demo in page. Trying being a bit more specific to what part of the page is not working. Thanks.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought it was simple just looking to the css reference and should be simple to understand which one I'd like to make display flex like container and the items. So how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you do so you'll stop getting downvotes and more answers. I can almost guarantee that you'd have an answer by now if you had when originally posting. Flexbox questions are quite common and there are a lot of knowledgable people on this site. You should make it as simple as possible for people to help you. Putting up barriers to help, i.e. no MVCE, will cause people to move on to the next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this and add a scroll

```
.flex-container {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

or remove the height and the container grow together.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I asked!!